# Null ids of array from ajax to actionresult in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, telerik-grid

My Ajax function:

```
function changeMultipleItemStatus(status) {
    var ids= getAllCheckedIds();
    var comment = $('#txtComment').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "../Admin/ChangeMultipleItemStatus",
        cache: false,
        data: {
            ids: ids,
            status: status,
            comment: comment
        },
        traditional: true,
        success: function (html) {
            ...
        }
    }); }
```

ActionResult

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ChangeMultipleItemStatus(int[] ids, string status, string comment)
{
  ....
}

function getAllCheckedIds() {
    var data = [];

    $("table input:checked").each(function () {
        data.push($(this).val());
    });

    return data;
}
```

My problem is ActionResult Changemultiplestatus first variable ids is always null. 
when i alert dataToSend it alert it seems okey (true,1,2) -> 1,2 is id of items.
But in controller action ids is always null.

any comments?

Comment: *"when i alert dataToSend it alert it seems okey (true,1,2) -> 1,2 is id of items"* And where's that `true` coming from? As it's not an `int`, that could be an issue...

Comment: I figure the odds of our needing to see the source of `getAllCheckedIds` is pretty high as well.

Comment: actually i dont know why it always containt a true at the beginning. items is listed in telerik grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you change `int[]` ids to string ids at webservice. Is it still null? Also try `[   [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]]` instead of `[HttpPost]`

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely **not** change the ints to strings. Phil Haack has a great piece on modelbinding to lists - there is some trickery involved when trying to do this, so I would suggest reading his article:
http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx